# Getting real north direction or real heading?

Tags: cesium

I try to get the north direction in a Cesium globe but it seems to always point to the viewer perspective.

Follow the compass instrument on top of the map:

This image I'm pointing (correctly?) to north:
[image]

Now, not soo good. I think the north is not there!
[image]

Even more strange:
[image]

This is how I'm getting the heading:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer',{
    terrainProvider : terrainProvider,
    timeline: false,
    animation: false,
    baseLayerPicker: false,
    skyAtmosphere: false,
    fullscreenButton : false,
    geocoder : false,
    homeButton : true,
    infoBox : false,
    sceneModePicker : true,
    selectionIndicator : false,
    timeline : false,
    navigationHelpButton : false,   
});

var camera = viewer.camera;

var heading = Cesium.Math.toDegrees( camera.heading );
```

I'm very new on Cesium and took this code from an example.

I need to always point to the real magnetic north.

---

Seems to get the "false" north or map north I need to:

`var heading = 360 - Cesium.Math.toDegrees( camera.heading );`

Now I need to point to magnetic north (without to calculate the Magnetic declination )

Comment: have you find a way to calculate ?

Comment: Not yet. It need some calculations and I can't do it for now.